# How to filter the listview based on Dropdown item click in android?

Tags: java, android, listview

I am developing an android application ,In that i have 3 tabs namely,

```
                 1.Invitation tab 
                 2.Event tab 
                 3.Groupchat tab
```

Invitation tab have the list of invitations ,Event tab have the list on events and Groupchat tab have the collection of invitation and event lists.
In my Group chat tab i have an icon "Dropdown"(Dropdown icon is presented in Dashboard) that have three items "All,Event,Invitation" that i am using for filter the Groupchat list items(it have collection of invitations and eventlists).Now my need is,

1. when i am ontap "event item"(event item is present with in dropdown icon,similarliy invite item and all item present with in dropdown),Groupchat tab only display the event list.
2. when ontap "invite item" invitation list is only display
3. when ontap "all item" i need to show both invitation and event lists.

How can i am achieve this,please suggest me the code..thanks for your help

My programming code is below,

```
public class GroupChatFragment extends Fragment {


    private Context context;
    private ListView chatListView;
    private TextView chatTitle;
    private TextView chatPlace;
    private TextView chatDate;
    private String dateResult;
    private List<EventMO> groupEventMoList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<EventMO> eventMOs = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<EventMO> invitationMOs = new ArrayList<>();
    private EventDelegates eventDelegates = new EventDelegates();
    private Gson gson = new Gson();
    private ProgressDialog prgDialog;
    private ChatDisplayAdapter chatDisplayAdapter;
    private ListView GroupEventView;
    private SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    private TextView eventList;
    private MessageMO messageMO = new MessageMO();

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.all:

                return true;
            case R.id.event:

                return true;
            case R.id.invitation:

                return true;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void Event() {
        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        final UserMO userMO = dbHelper.getRingeeUserData(1);
        eventMOs = gson.fromJson(eventDelegates.getAllEventFromUser(userMO, context), new TypeToken<List<EventMO>>() {
        }.getType());
        List<EventMO> groupEventMOList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (EventMO eventMO : eventMOs) {
            groupEventMOList.add(eventMO);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chatwindow_tab, container, false);
        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        final UserMO userMO = dbHelper.getRingeeUserData(1);
        prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        prgDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        // Set Cancelable as False
        prgDialog.setCancelable(false);
        prgDialog.show();
        //inviation group for user
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<EventMO>>() {
            @Override
            protected List<EventMO> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                eventMOs = gson.fromJson(eventDelegates.getAllEventFromUser(userMO, context), new TypeToken<List<EventMO>>() {
                }.getType());
                invitationMOs = gson.fromJson(eventDelegates.getAllEventForUser(userMO, context), new TypeToken<List<EventMO>>() {
                }.getType());
                List<EventMO> groupEventMOList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (EventMO eventMO : eventMOs) {
                    groupEventMOList.add(eventMO);

                }
                for (EventMO eventMO : invitationMOs) {
                    groupEventMOList.add(eventMO);

                }
                return groupEventMOList;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<EventMO> groupEventMOList) {
                groupEventMoList = groupEventMOList;
                prgDialog.dismiss();
                DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
                //long totalInsertion = dbHelper.insertUserRelationTable(userMOs);
                //Toast.makeText(context, "total userMos size " + userMOs.size() + "total db insertion size " + totalInsertion, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                GroupEventView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.chat_list_view);
                chatDisplayAdapter = new ChatDisplayAdapter();
                GroupEventView.setAdapter(chatDisplayAdapter);
                GroupEventView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
                GroupEventView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
                GroupEventView.setOnItemClickListener(GroupEventView.getOnItemClickListener());
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
        return view;
    }


    private class ChatDisplayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public ChatDisplayAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return groupEventMoList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return groupEventMoList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int id) {
            // for sqllite management
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.chatwindow, null);
                convertView.setClickable(true);
                convertView.setFocusable(true);

                chatTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chat_title);
                chatPlace = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_place);
                chatDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_date);
                chatPlace.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                chatDate.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                chatTitle.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                chatPlace.setText(groupEventMoList.get(position).getPlace());
                String actualDate = groupEventMoList.get(position).getEventDate();
                //chatDate.setText(groupEventMoList.get(position).getEventDate());
                try {
                    //date format changed here
                    Date formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(actualDate);
                    dateResult = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(formatDate);
                } catch (ParseException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                chatDate.setText(dateResult);
                chatTitle.setText(groupEventMoList.get(position).getText());
                convertView.setTag(position);
                View v = convertView.findViewById(R.id.chat_window_single);
                v.getRootView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.i("position", v.getTag().toString());
                        Intent groupAct = new Intent(context, GroupChatActivity.class);
                        groupAct.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        groupAct.putExtra("eventMo", groupEventMoList.get(Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString())));
                        startActivity(groupAct);
                    }

                });
            }
            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```